# As of Nov 2018, is it possible to take a week vacation/break between jobs while on H1B (after receiving the receipt number)?

Tags: working-visas, h1-visa

I'm currently employed and found a new job. The other company filed the H1 transfer and yet to receive the receipt number. I was planning on taking a week vacation between the jobs. Once I receive the receipt number of transfer, Can I take one week break and join the new company? Will that cause any issues in future? I don't have any green card processed.

Comment: Is your week break within the United States or in another country?

Comment: Yes.. it’s within United States